# Beautiful Soup - Grabbing the string after the first specified tag

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab the string immediately after the opening `<td>` tag.  The following code works:

```
webpage = urlopen(i).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
for elem in soup('td', text=re.compile(".\.doc")):
    print elem.parent
```

when the html looks like this:

`<td>plan_49913.doc</td>`

but not when the html looks like this:

`<td>plan_49913.doc<br />
<font color="#990000">Document superseded by: &#160;</font><a href="/plans/Jan_2012.html">January 2012</a></td>`

I've tried playing with attrs but can't get it to work. Basically I just want to grab 'plan_49913.doc' in either instance of html.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

~chrisK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `next` property, it contains the next node, and that's a textual node.

```
>>> html = '<td>plan_49913.doc<br /> <font color="#990000">Document superseded by: &#160;</font><a href="/plans/Jan_2012.html">January 2012</a></td>'
>>> bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> texts = [ node.next for node in bs.findAll('td') if node.next.endswith('.doc') ]
>>> texts
[u'plan_49913.doc']
```

you can change the `if` clause to use a regex if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks you. This works... unfortunately, I'm struggling to comprehend the syntax in the "texts =" line. Would you be kind enough to break it down and structure it like:

'for ....
    print'

Comment: That's a list comprehension. It's a shortcut equivalent to:
    `texts = [];`
    `for node in bs.findAll('td'):` 
        `if node.next.endswith('.doc'):`
            `texts.append(node.next)`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
>>> html = '<td>plan_49913.doc<br /> <font color="#990000">Document superseded by: &#160;</font><a href="/plans/Jan_2012.html">January 2012</a></td>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.find(text=re.compile('.\.doc'))
u'plan_49913.doc
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Also, note that according to the documentation:

> If you use text, then any values you give for name and the keyword arguments are ignored.

So you don't need to pass `'td'` since it's already being ignored, that is, any text that matches under any other tag will be returned.